# How to remove EXIF metadata of images from page using JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, exif

I have image upload functionality in my website. But some images shows correct orientation on the desktop but their rotation changes on iPhone.
I found out that these images are having EXIF metadata. So How to remove this metadata and show correct orientation of images in iPhone and iPad.